# Hierarchical logging of MobX derivations/computeds

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have a complex network of derivations that runs great (thanks MobX!) but I'd like to present a user-facing visualization of some of the changes, each with respect to the upstream dependencies that necessitated the change, within the context of a single transaction — i.e. I'm trying to create a data structure that's in some sense isomorphic with the tree of changed computeds so that I can present a kind of hierarchical log. e.g.

Example:
[image]

Before using Mobx, the computed functions were 'update' functions. I could construct an isomorphic log by relying on the call stack and pushing and popping contexts. (In most cases it was safe to assume that if an update was running there was a difference to log but in many cases a previous value was cached to compare against). e.g.

```
updateA(){
    pushLog("A") // creates "A" log node.
    if ... updateX()
    else ... updateB();
    popLog()
}
updateB(){
    pushLog("B") // creates "B" log node.
    updateC()
    if ...  updateX()
    popLog(); // Remove the B log node, assuming everything else is pushing and popping as it should. 
}

updateC(){
   pushLog("C")
   //...
   popLog();
}

updateX(){
   pushLog("X")
   //...
   popLog();
}
```

With computeds and reactions though there is no clean call stack, so I'm not sure how to properly construct an isomorphic log tree.

I can create reactions for each computed but they will of course run at the end and without a guaranteed order and sans any kind of info on the chain-of-causation so to say.

It smells like I might be able to *assemble* the log tree after the fact if I kept track of the computed's debug names and then do some kind of dependency lookup in a reaction before appending the log entry — see if a previous entry in the log is a dependency, and if so, append the new log entry to that previous entry. But the log itself is an observable and updating it *after* the transaction will create other complications — ideally the transaction that triggers the computed would contain the changes to the log.

It may also be possible to do the logging in the computed's themselves but in common case where a computed has multiple dependencies, we still need to know which dependency or dependencies triggered the computed. While it's possible to track previous values and do comparisons and such, given that MobX is *already doing that*, it seems pretty redundant.

--

Context:

Consider that in many boardgames many rules can be functionally expressed. e.g. In Catan, whether a player is a winner is a function of their total points and that total is a function of each players' connected roads (plus some other things).

Presenting a UI-celebration when `player.won == true` is trivial but it would be *ideal* to indicate that this winning was contingent on, for example, becoming the player with longest road and that was contingent on the player's road pieces. i.e.

> Placed road
>
> > Secured "Longest Road"! +10 points
> >
> > > Victory!

To communicate these contingencies we need to know not just the initiating change (change in placed roads) but also the chain of derivations that led to a change in `player.won`.

This is especially necessary where there exists multiple paths through the dependency tree from an initial change to an ending change. For example, imagine a Catan variant where placing a road could create a board situation where it was known to be logically impossible for any other player to win thereafter, resulting in a weird win-by-default...

> Placed road
>
> > All opponents boxed in.
> >
> > > Victory!

Answer (score 0):

If by “log” you just mean `console.log` then it’s simple as a one-liner, using the [trace](https://mobx.js.org/analyzing-reactivity.html#using-trace-for-debugging) API.

```
import { trace } from "mobx"
trace(player, "won")
```

I don’t know about other programmatic API in MobX to access the dep graph info though.

Comment: "If by “log” you just mean console.log" 
Apologies, afraid not. Updated question's first paragraph to clarify.